# Storing elements in a property using modular Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var menu = {

    //The elements we'll be using in the Menu
    elements: {},
    el: this.elements, //Doesn't work


    init: function() {


        el.$header = $('header');
        el.$myDiv = $('.arrow');

        el.$myDiv.on('click', function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            menu.open();
        });

    },


    open: function() {

        el.$header.addClass('whatever');
        ...
```

I'm trying to learn some best practices for Javascript, and I'm having trouble with references to elements. I have an object, `elements`, which will be populated with variables which represent elements in the DOM. These variables are added to this object when `menu.init` is called (when the window has loaded, otherwise it fails).

Rather than have to type `menu.elements` or `this.elements` every time, I'd rather just store it as a variable, such as `el`. My current implementation gives the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined`. How can I make this work?

Comment: inside init: this.elements?

Comment: That' be because `this.elements` is actually looking at `window.elements` because of what `this` is referencing. It seems like you actually want to create [an object prototype](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just have an inner function variable:

```
var menu = {

//The elements we'll be using in the Menu
elements: {},
init: function() {
  var el=this.elements;

    el.$header = $('header');
    el.$myDiv = $('.arrow');

    el.$myDiv.on('click', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        menu.open();
    });

},
```

By the way

```
el:this.elements
```

wont work. Object properties cannot access each other on creation.

Comment: So I have to set it for each function within menu?

Comment: George commented on the question saying that 'this.elements' was looking at 'windows.elements'. Is this incorrect?

Comment: @nicedevman no this is correct. being in an objects function or in an object makes a big difference concerning context

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help, Jonas.